# find all certificate files in any centos directory using the expiry date filter

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, certificate

Please, I need to find all certificate files in any directory in the centos box.

I tried the "find" with "exec" command and grep "not after". This display only the expiry dates of the certificates but I need to find the actual files too:

```
find /etc/  -type f -exec openssl x509 -in {} -noout -text \; |
grep -i  "not after"
```

what command could list the cert files with the content of their expiry dates too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version with a helper-script:

`cat /root/expiry.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
expiry=$(openssl x509 -in $name -noout -text 2>/dev/null | grep -i "not after")
if [[  $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "${name}\t${expiry}"
fi
```

Execute like so:

```
find /etc/  -type f -exec /root/expiry.sh "{}" \;
/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem                Not After : Mar 30 22:59:59 2027 GMT
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt              Not After : Dec 31 09:37:37 2030 GMT
```

Comment: I'm glad you liked that approach. :)

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help Tink. I am really sorry, for coming back a bit late

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `find + awk`:

```sh
while IFS= read -rd '' cert; do
   printf '%s :: ' "$cert"
   openssl x509 -in "$cert" -noout -text |
   awk -F ' *Not After : ' 'NF == 2 {print $2; exit}'
done < <(find /etc -type f -print0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help anubhava. I am really sorry, for coming back a bit late but I could not get that script to run. I ran it as script and directly from the shell but could not get it to work